# CSS: mix-blend-mode makes transform not work anymore (Chrome, Firefox)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, transform, mix-blend-mode

Seems like `mix-blend-mode: multiply` makes any `transform` not work anymore.
This happens in Chrome and Firefox, while on Safari it works. (All updated to the last version)

In this fiddle you can see the behaviour: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/113292/)
(Sorry if it's a bit messy, I'm not a developer)

The first image is without the `multiply` class, while the second is with it.

```
.inner {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(30px);
  transform: translateZ(30px);
}

.innerUp {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(100px);
  transform: translateZ(100px);
}

.multiply {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

I've found some discussion on this, but none of them managed to solve the issue.

Thanks!